# Tensorflow uses memory from both graphic cards but training runs on only one graphic card

Tags: tensorflow

I am training the neural network on multi-GPU system (2 GPU). I am using only one GPU, but the program use memory from both of them. For using only one card I am using this part of code:

```
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
```

But it still using memory from both of them. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code that you provided does not make your code run on one card/GPU, but run on the CPU.

If you have two video cards available for training, you can first verify that they are both visible via this line of code.

```
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(gpus)
```

In your case, the print from above should give you information about both video cards.

If you want to restrict the usage to only one GPU/video card for training, the solution is to use the following code:

```
   import os 
   os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0' OR os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'
```

In this case, the tensorflow program will only use either the video card with index 0 or the video card with index 1 (note that the indices start from 0, in reality, it would use either GPU 1 or GPU 2, depending on the order that tensorflow assigns it to your GPUs).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question - I am using `with tf.device('/GPU:0'):`